# In Java, how do i search for this certain regex?

Tags: java, regex, string, function, search

I want a function to search a string to see if it contains $[0-9] or $[a-f,A-F]

So like, if it contains $a or even $e it'll turn true.

Comment: Take the regex trail: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/intro.html

Comment: You only care about one character after the dollar sign? You just care about truth, not the values themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex is `/\$[A-Fa-f0-9]/` and you might use it like so:

```
Pattern.matches("\$[A-Fa-f0-9]", yourString);
```

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Java docs, very straightforward:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29

Answer (score 0):

create regex with the help of this tutorial :
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html

use matches() method from String class :
http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: I know that but how do i add the cash sign in a regex expersion?

Comment: think you need to escape it ... \$